# How to use jq to produce two subsequent lines?

Tags: json, terminal, jq

I can use following jq commands to produce two files:

```
cat test.json | jq '{ "index" : { "_index" : "items1", "_id" : .hits.hits[]._source.item_id  } }' -c > test_itemids.json
```

and

```
cat test.json | jq '.hits.hits[]._source' -c > test_source.json
```

As a result, I get the following two files:

```
{"index":{"_index":"items1","_id":8021096}}
{"index":{"_index":"items1","_id":8021446}}
{"index":{"_index":"items1","_id":8023950}}
...
```

and

```
{source1...}
{source2...}
```

My goal is though to produce one file with the content:

```
{"index":{"_index":"items1","_id":8021096}}
{source1...}
{"index":{"_index":"items1","_id":8021446}}
{source2...}
{"index":{"_index":"items1","_id":8023950}}
...
```

How could I combine the jq commands above to one single command producing one file?

Comment: Please post the content of `test.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`,` is your friend:

```
.hits.hits[]._source
| (., {"index" : { "_index" : "items1", "_id" : .item_id  } })
```

(The outer parens can be omitted but are included in case that makes things clearer.)